# FancyBox too big div

Tags: jquery, css, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to display pics with FancyBox. When I click on a pic it looks bad? What is causing this?

See the following example:

[image: Image with problem]

Code from fireBug:

```
<head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="fancybox-overlay" style="display: block; width: 1000px;"></div>
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-image fancybox-opened" tabindex="-1" style="width: 163px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 989px; left: 593px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible;">
<div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;">
<div class="fancybox-outer">
<a class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" title="Close"></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my div

```
    div {
  position: relative;

  background-color:#25b025;
  width: 1024px;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 

  border: none;
  /*border: 1px black solid;*/

  margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: If you don't give part of the code and try to explain what you've tried to do it'll be really hard to help you out.

Comment: Look what happens when You click on thumbnail at the bottom: http://spmiekinia.cba.pl/index.php?id=6&tyt=Magia+%C5%9Awi%C4%85t+w+Jase%C5%82kach

Comment: @PawalZielkowski the `DOCTYPE` has to be the very fist line of your html document

Comment: @PawalZielkowski I see that ins't a nice behavior but it depends on how you want the images to be displayed, if what you want is to make all the pics look with the same dimensions  then you should give them same dimensions.

Comment: @JFK what when I havel php file when I require html file. DOCTYPE should be in php file or html file ?

Comment: @HectorWilliam Thanks for replay. I can't imagine all pic I will get will be same dimension :)

Comment: @PawalZielkowski : if your html is being rendered by a php file, then set `DOCTYPE` in the php file and as FIRST line (right now is not); all html files (with few exceptions when they are called via ajax) should have a `DOCTYPE` in the first line. BTW, ignore @HectorWilliam's  comment regarding image dimensions, it has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: @PawalZielkowski : no offense but some basic html tutorials won't hurt you ;)